# aggregate values in SQL columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am SQL beginner and I have the following question:

I have the following data (article sales by week)

```
COUNT   WEEK    ART
4           1   A
9           1   B

5           2   A
4           2   B

6           3   A
5           3   B

7           4   A
2           4   B
```

I would like to have the following output

```
ODD_WEEK    EVEN_WEEK   ART
10          12          A
14          6           B
```

in other words, I would like to group the elements by a criteria in a column (ODD_WEEK) and by an other criteria in another column (EVEN_WEEK)

Is it possible in T-SQL?

Comment: Yes it is possible, you need to Group by-s.

Comment: GroupBy is not sufficient, I din't know about conditional SUM... Thanks to @Meherzad

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this query

```
select
   art,
   sum(case when week%2=0 then count else 0 end) even,
   sum(case when week%2<>0 then count else 0 end) odd
from 
   tbl
group by 
   art
```

### **[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/0e662/1)**

```
| ART | EVEN | ODD |
|-----|------|-----|
|   A |   12 |  10 |
|   B |    6 |  14 |
```